# AngularJS Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found an example of code like this one in a github project, and it works fine.

```
function myFunc($par1, $par2) {
    //some stuff here
}
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(['$par1', '$par2', myFunc]);
```

Now I am trying to apply it to some code I have to update, here the function is declared like this:

```
module.exports = /* @ngInject */ function myFunc($par1, $par2) {
```

and I am getting an error saying

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
```

So, how can I refer to `myFunc` when declared in `module.export`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to require the module and assign the exported value to a variable or constant:

```
const myFunc = require("module-that-exports-myFunc");
```

Comment: and where can I find the module name definition? note all this is in the same file...